# Application Control Scripts on Unix

Tags: linux, unix, solaris, scripting

I'm looking for some software that allows me to control a server based application, that is, there are bunch of interdependent processes that I'd like to be able to start up, shut down and monitor in a controller manner.

I've come across programs like Autosys, but that's expensive and very much over the top for what I want. I've also seen [AppCtl](http://appctl.sourceforge.net/), but that seems not to handle dependencies. Maybe it would be possible to repurpose the init scripts?

Oh, and as an added complication it should be able to run on a Solaris 10 or Linux box without installing any new binaries. On the boxes I've seen recently, that means shell scripts and Perl but not Python.

Do any such programs exist or do I need to dust off my copy of Programming Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Supervise, which is what qmail uses to keep track of it's services/startup applications:

http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/supervise.html

Answer (score 1):

G'day,

Have a look in /etc/init.d for something similar and use that as a basis. See also crontab, or maybe at, to run on a regular basis.

cheers,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Solaris-only as far as I know, but wouldn't Solaris 10's [SMF](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/selfheal/smf-quickstart.jsp) do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try GNU Batch. It looks like it supports what you need.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gnubatch/